# Getting swagger/swashbuckle to show basic info about a controller and ignoring return type?

Tags: swagger

Im using swashbuckle with visual studio 2012 to create API documentation for a project, for one controller the return type results in the error "Swagger does not support containers of containers" because of a nested structure.

Im currently using [System.Web.Http.Description.ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)] to remove this method from the docs, but is there any way to instruct swagger/swashbuckle to ignore the processing of the return type so I can show the rest of the information for the method - i could then add the necessary information in the documentation tags.